# Automator & AppleScript: How do I import the texts of Notes and Reminders as PDFs and RTFs?

Tags: pdf, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, rtf, automator

I would like to import and save the Notes and Reminders documents or texts as PDFs and RTFs, keeping or preserving the formation and the background of Notes or Reminders, but the Notes doesn't have the option.

I would like to know if it's possible to use Automator and AppleScript to import the Notes and Reminders as PDFs and RTFs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Gmail account, you can move your notes to it in Notes and then move them to some other folder in Gmail's web interface. You can then select the notes in Mail and save them as plain text or rich text (but not PDF).

If you just need a list of reminders as plain text, Reminders has support for AppleScript.

```
set output to ""
tell application "Reminders"
    repeat with l in lists
        set output to output & linefeed & "## " & name of l & linefeed & linefeed
        repeat with r in reminders of l
            set l to "- " & name of r
            set output to output & l & linefeed
            -- properties of r
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
-- set the clipboard to output
```

Comment: When I run Applescript with Reminders, where do I find the documents exported?

Comment: It just prints the names of tasks and lists as plain text. I don't know any way to include the background texture or anything.